# TextField becomes empty when selecting another

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a strange case. I am using four text fields in iOS 10. The text field has text but it becomes empty when selecting another text field. My class is `UITextFieldDelegate` to these text fields. What could be the issue? I've attached images which shows the case.

Text field (Idle Time Out) becomes empty when resignFirstResponder

[image]

Another text field (Slide Time Out) becomes empty when resignFirstResponder.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Firstly , I am reseting the textfield by this function:

```
func resetTextField(){

    self.slideTimeOutTxtField.resignFirstResponder()
    self.idelTimeOutTxtField.resignFirstResponder()
    self.idelTimeOutTxtField.resignFirstResponder()
    self.passwordTxtField.resignFirstResponder()
    self.longPressDurationTxtField.resignFirstResponder()
    self.slideTimeOutTxtField.layer.borderWidth = 0
    self.idelTimeOutTxtField.layer.borderWidth = 0
    self.passwordTxtField.layer.borderWidth = 0
    self.longPressDurationTxtField.layer.borderWidth = 0

    let slideTimeOut =  DatabaseController.settings.last?.slideTimeOut
    let idelTimeOut = DatabaseController.settings.last?.idleTimeOut
    let password = DatabaseController.settings.last?.password
    let longPressDuration = DatabaseController.settings.last?.longPressDuration
    self.slideTimeOutTxtField.text =  (slideTimeOut != nil ) ?  ("\(String(describing: slideTimeOut!))") : ""
    self.idelTimeOutTxtField.text =  (idelTimeOut != nil) ?    ("\(String(describing: idelTimeOut!))") : ""
    self.passwordTxtField.text =  (password != nil) ?  password : ""
    self.longPressDurationTxtField.text = (longPressDuration != nil) ? ("\(String(describing: longPressDuration!))") : ""

}
```

Then I am implementing them by theses functions:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    switch textField {
    case self.idelTimeOutTxtField , self.slideTimeOutTxtField , self.longPressDurationTxtField :
        if  ((string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits)) != nil) || (string.isEmpty){ //isEmpty when delete on character
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    default:
        return true
    }

}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 0
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.okBtnAction(self.okBtn)
    return true 
}
```

I put TextFields inside another view as in the image[TextFields are placed inside another View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTPz1.png) , would that has any effect?

I upload animated GIF of what is going on on this: https://imgur.com/a/v3x4j

Comment: How are you implementing these text fields? Could you share some code? I suspect something is going on with your text field delegate methods, but can’t tell from a screenshot.

Comment: You need to show the code for these `UITextFields` so we can see what's happening.

Comment: You need to explain how&when resetTextField() gets called.  Is it just wired to your viewDidLoad() and the Cancel button?

Comment: resetTextField() gets called on viewdidLoad function

Comment: BTW, here's a better way to restrict those 3 fields to just numerics:  `let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)`.  Your approach just tests if any character in the text has a number.

Comment: unfortunately , still have the same issue and could not able to find the probelm.